# Excel VBA Autofilter error when using criteria2

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2016 fr 32 bits, Windows 10

I want to filter dates for the month of january. The macro recorder gives:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "1/1/2020")
```

When I play it back if get  a "Autofilter method of Range class failed Run-time  Error 1004".
Important note. The same code works fine on the same computer with Excel 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing `Criteria1`

Comment: This code is the macro recorder output. Moreover, it runs fine with Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Criteria2` is used when values of two criterias are compared (`AND`, or `OR`). For more info see: [`XlAutoFilterOperator` doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilteroperator).

If you want to filter values (what you probably want because operator [`xlFilterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilteroperator#:%7E:text=xlFilterValues,values)), you need to pass `Variant Array` (1 based) to `Criteria1`

Something like this:

```vb
Dim WantedVals as Variant
ReDim WantedVals(1 to n)

WantedVals(1) = "1/1/2020"
'...
WantedVals(n) = "12/1/2099"

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=WantedVals
```

*Your code was probably generated this way, because you add second value during macro recording. When two values are filtered Excel internally changes the filter operator to `OR` and then use `Criteria1 = Value1` and `Criteria2 = Value2`.*

**Note ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter#:%7E:text=when%20using%20autofilter%20with%20dates%2C%20the%20format%20should%20be%20consistent%20with%20english%20date%20separators%20(%22%2F%22)%20instead%20of%20local%20settings%20(%22.%22).%20a%20valid%20date%20would%20be%20%222%2F2%2F2007%22%2C%20whereas%20%222.2.2007%22%20is%20invalid.)):**
When using `AutoFilter` with dates, the format should be consistent with English date separators (`/`) instead of local settings (`.`). A valid date would be `2/2/2007`, whereas `2.2.2007` is invalid.

Comment: Changing Criteria2 to Criteria1 works. I do have a question though. Why does the macro 
works on my laptop without any issue, but I'm encountering error on my desktop? Both of them has 2016 version.

Comment: @Lien0 Just guessing, but maybe different locale?