# how do i create/pass a variant in order to filter multiple criteria using win32com

Tags: python, vba, win32com

i am not strong with VBA, but as i understand it `AutoFilter` requires an `Array()` Variant when running `xlFilterValues`.

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
mv_wbk = excel.ActiveWorkbook
mv_sht = mv_wbk.Worksheets("mv")

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilteroperator
xlFilterValues = 7
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.varianttype?view=net-6.0
arrayId = 8192

fltrs = win32.VARIANT(arrayId,["uno","dos"])
mv_sht.UsedRange.AutoFilter(Field=15,Criteria1=f'<>Array{fltrs}',Operator=xlFilterValues)
```

when i run this, it returns `15.0`, i'm guessing because that's the field.  I've tried all variations i could think of, as well as looking at other stackoverflows - but there isn't much info on this.

best i found:
[Excel VBA Autofilter error when using criteria2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899809/excel-vba-autofilter-error-when-using-criteria2)
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/variant.html

but doens't apply it to `AutoFilter`

Thanks!

Comment: You can also add complex criteria using the AdvancedFilter https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b#bkmk_1  Though you don't get the filter symbol on the column headers (you may not care). Basically you define the filter in a range on your spreadsheet, and provide that range to the AdvancedFilter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rnd om says above you can't filter **out** (ie <>) multiple criteria, but you can filter in.

One workaround is to create a unique list of the values in your filter column, remove the ones you don't want, and filter **in** the remainder. It is perhaps not ideal but might be a possible solution. Incidentally this is what Excel does if you 'Select All' in a filter, and then deselect items.

Here's some test data:

[image]

This Python code *filters out lines* where the 3rd Letter is 'e' or 'h':

```
import win32com.client

wbPath ='C:\\SomePath\\Filter.xlsx'

xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

#Access a named range with the table data
rng = ws.Range('TableRange')

#Get all the values from 3rd column in Range
vals = rng.Columns(3).Value

#Create a dictionary of unique values (skipping the header row)
#(there may be more pythonic ways of doing this!)
keepVals = { val[0]:None for val in vals[1:]}

#Remove any values from exclude list
valsToExclude = ['e','h']
[keepVals.pop(v) for v in valsToExclude]

#Create Criteria1 array as a list
crit = ["=" + k for k in keepVals.keys()]

#Apply the filter
rng.AutoFilter(Field=3,Criteria1=crit,Operator=win32com.client.constants.xlFilterValues)

wb.Close(True)
xl.Quit()
xl = None
```

With this result in the saved file:
[image]

Comment: i like this, because i can create a class or function that will filter whatever input, and don't need to lose data or change the sheet.

Comment: Cool. Though if you add rows to the table, you will need to rerun the filter. For just two exclusions using Criteria1 and Criteria 2 with xlAnd might be more robust. As an aside, using `win32com.client.gencache.constants` means you don’t have to define the constants yourself (eg xlFilterValues): they are generated from the Excel type library.

Answer (score 1):

From various sources, it seems that you cannot filter **out** multiple criteria (i.e. exclude them from a filter).

You have to remove them from the sheet. So an array with `<>`'s doesn't work.

```py
xlCellTypeVisible = 12
xlShiftUp = -4162
cols = mv_sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
for owner in ["uno","dos"]:
    mv_sht.UsedRange.AutoFilter(Field=15, Criteria1=owner)
    lastRow = mv_sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder=1, SearchDirection=2).Row
    mv_sht.Range(mv_sht.Cells(2, 1), mv_sht.Cells(lastRow, cols)).SpecialCells(Type=xlCellTypeVisible).Delete(
            Shift=xlShiftUp)
```

So, I just looped over each value of the array, filtered the sheet, and deleted those rows.

This seems terribly inefficient though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are quoting the array like that. 
The call on VBA should look like this

```
RangeObjectToFilter.AutoFilter 
  Field:=ColumnNumber, 
  Criteria1:=ArrayMultipleCriteria, 
  Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

And I would try to declare the array like this:

```
ArrayMultipleCriteria = Array(10, 20, 30, "SomeValue")
```

You have to adjust the python code accordingly and I believe this should do the trick:

```
mv_sht.UsedRange.AutoFilter(Field=15,Criteria1=f'Array({', '.join(fltrs)})',
  Operator=xlFilterValues)
```

Comment: i changed the ```f string``` to include double quotes.  but regardless, i'm left with a filter that shows nothing.  very odd.

i did solve this by just looping.  although i imagine it's much slower than should be.  I'll post my answer but wont give it the check.

Comment: Does it work with this hardcoded version?
`ArrayMultipleCriteria = Array("uno", "dos")`
Also, you could try including double quotes

Comment: i've tried that, i'm not sure if win32com allows for variants inside a string??

Comment: win32com will create the variant array for you from a Python list. So `Criteria1=[10,20,30,'SomeValue']`