# Range.AutoFilter method and Filter object's properties

Tags: excel, vba

This question concerns the Range.AutoFilter method and the Filter object's properties.

Suppose column A contains dates for the first of each month in 2022 with a text header in row 1. With cell A1 selected, I can use the ribbon (Home > Editing > Filter) to enable AutoFilter for column A. With the macro recorder ON, I can use the mouse to filter for January, March, and May, then stop the macro recorder. Here is the result:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$13").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "1/1/2022", 1, "3/1/2022", 1, "5/1/2022")
```

Then this code will print True, 7 (xlFilterValues), and 0 (?):

```
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1)
    Debug.Print .On, .Operator, .Count
End With
```

But VBA Debug indicates that neither of these properties is defined:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1).Criteria2
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1).Criteria1
```

Where is the list of filtered dates originally defined as Criteria2?

After first clearing the filter, if I run the original macro recorder code the range is filtered as expected; however, this code will print True, 0 (?), and 0 instead of True, 7, and 0 as expected:

```
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1)
    Debug.Print .On, .Operator, .Count
End With
```

What happened to Filter.Operator? Apparently the Range.AutoFilter method does not populate the Filter object's properties as expected.

Comment: Works fine if you use `Criteria1` for the array.  I don't know why the macro recorder has `Criteria2`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899809/excel-vba-autofilter-error-when-using-criteria2

Comment: I tested this out myself, and got the same result that you described. My suspicion would be that it has something to do with the fact that the `Criteria2` argument is an `Array` of unknown length when `Operator=xlFilterValues` -- but, I'm just speculating. If you record a macro to set e.g. Date Filters > Between... with 2 dates, then it *will* populate all of `Criteria1`, `Criteria2`, and `Operator`, whether you do it in the UI or by running the recorded macro.

Comment: If I modify the macro recorder's code to reference Criteria1 instead of Criteria2, it does not filter the range as  intended. In fact, all rows become hidden. However, the Filter object's properties become True, 7, and 3 as expected. The Range.AutoFIlter document says Criteria2 "used as single criteria on date fields filtering by date, month or year. ...Array(Level, Date)... Level is 0-2 (year,month,date) and Date is one valid Date." I conclude the Filter object's properties are not populated when filtering by specific dates (3 or more).

Answer (score 0):

[My Excel Toolbox](https://sites.google.com/view/MyExcelToolbox) includes the following dynamic array function to list a worksheet's auto filters (Data > Filter):

```
=ListAutoFilters([Target],[SkipHeader])
```

It returns three rows (filter range, head cell's value, filter criteria) for Target's worksheet with one column for each filter plus an optional header column. Here is a partial listing that deals with the .Criteria1 and .Criteria2 problems indicated above when .Operator is xlFilterValues and 3 or more non-consecutive dates are specified:

```
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(n)
    Select Case .Operator
    '''
    Case xlFilterValues
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsArray(.Criteria1) Then
        If Err = 0 Then
            sFilt = ""
            kU = UBound(.Criteria1)
            For k = LBound(.Criteria1) To kU
                sFilt = sFilt & .Criteria1(k) & IIf(k < kU, ",", "")
            Next k
        Else
            Err.Clear
            If IsArray(.Criteria2) Then
                If Err = 0 Then
                    sYrMoDa = Split("Year ,Month ,Day ", ",")
                    sFilt = ""
                    kU = UBound(.Criteria2)
                    For k = LBound(.Criteria2) To kU Step 2
                        sFilt = sFilt & sYrMoDa(.Criteria2(k)) & .Criteria2(k + 1) & IIf((k + 1) < kU, ",", "")
                    Next k
                ElseIf .Count = 0 Then
                    sFilt = "Certain Dates"
                Else
                    sFilt = "Certain Values"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    '''
    End Select
End With
```

When 3 or more non-date values are specified, .Criteria1 is defined as Array (Err is False). Until M fixes the problem described in my original question, .Criteria1 and .Criteria2 are both undefined (Err is True) and .Count is zero when 3 or more date values are specified. If and when M fixes the problem, .Criteria2 should agree with the Range.AutoFIlter document: "...used as single criteria on date fields filtering by date, month or year. ...Array(Level, Date)... Level is 0-2 (year,month,date) and Date is one valid Date." In that case, sFilt will update appropriately (the second Err is False).